JavaScript: Issue with Calculating Age from Date of Birth in Form Data and display age on text field
I'm trying to calculate the age based on a date of birth (DOB) input in a form using JavaScript. I've set up a form where users can input their first name, last name, gender, and DOB. The DOB should be used to calculate the age, which is then displayed in the form. It is a multi step form
the first step of the from here is the code

<div class="col-lg-2 mb-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-label">First Name*</label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control " placeholder="FirstName"  >
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                  
                                                 <div class="col-lg-2 mb-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-label">Last Name*</label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="LastName" >
                                                    </div>
                                                 </div>



div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-label">Date of Birth*</label>
                                                        <input type="text" name="dob" class=" form-control" placeholder="DateOfBirth" id="mdate-3">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>


<div class="row"> <!-- 3rd row -->
                                                    <!-- drop dowwn with gender -->
                                                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                                    <label>Select Gender*</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="inputState" name="Gender" >
                                                    <option selected disabled>Choose...</option>
                                                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="text-label">Number of Adults*</label>
                                                        <input type="number" name="numberofAdults" id = "numberofAdults" min ="0"   class="form-control" onchange="addAdultFields()" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>


here is the javascript
// Define a global object to hold form data
var formData = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  gender: '',
  dob: ''
};

// Function to save form data
function saveFormData() {
  const firstNameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]');
  const lastNameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="lastName"]');
  const genderSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="Gender"]');
  const dobInput = document.querySelector('input[name="dob"]');

  if (firstNameInput) formData.firstName = firstNameInput.value;
  if (lastNameInput) formData.lastName = lastNameInput.value;
  if (genderSelect) formData.gender = genderSelect.value;
  if (dobInput) formData.dob = dobInput.value;

  console.log('Data saved to formData:', formData);
}

// Add event listeners
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const firstNameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]');
  const lastNameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="lastName"]');
  const genderSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="Gender"]');
  const dobInput = document.querySelector('input[name="dob"]');

  if (firstNameInput) firstNameInput.addEventListener('input', saveFormData);
  if (lastNameInput) lastNameInput.addEventListener('input', saveFormData);
  if (genderSelect) genderSelect.addEventListener('change', saveFormData);
  if (dobInput) dobInput.addEventListener('input', saveFormData);
});

// Function to calculate age based on date of birth
function calculateAge(dob) {
  console.log('Calculating age for dob:', dob); // Debugging line
  if (!dob) {
    console.log('DOB is empty');
    return '';
  }
  const birthDate = new Date(dob);
  console.log('Parsed birthDate:', birthDate); // Debugging line
  if (isNaN(birthDate.getTime())) {
    console.log('Invalid date of birth:', dob); // Debugging line
    return '';
  }
  const today = new Date();
  let age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  const monthDifference = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (monthDifference < 0 || (monthDifference === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
  }
  console.log('Calculated age:', age); // Debugging line
  return age;
}

function addAdultFields() {
  var numAdults = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberofAdults").value, 10);
  var parent = document.getElementById("adultFormcontainer");

  // Clear existing form fields
  parent.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < numAdults; i++) {
    var fieldset = document.createElement("fieldset");
    fieldset.style.display = "flex";
    fieldset.style.flexDirection = "row";
    fieldset.style.marginBottom = '100px';
    fieldset.style.paddingTop = '5px';
    fieldset.classList.add("float-left");

    var legend = document.createElement("legend");
    legend.textContent = i === 0 ? "Head of Household" : "Adult " + i;
    fieldset.appendChild(legend);

    var fields = [
      { label: "First Name", name: i === 0 ? "firstName" : "adult" + i + "FirstName", type: "text", value: i === 0 ? formData.firstName : "" },
      { label: "Last Name", name: i === 0 ? "lastName" : "adult" + i + "LastName", type: "text", value: i === 0 ? formData.lastName : "" },
      { label: "Gender", name: i === 0 ? "gender" : "adult" + i + "Gender", type: "select", options: ["Male", "Female"], selected: i === 0 ? formData.gender : "" },
      { label: "Age", name: "age", type: "text", value: i === 0 ? calculateAge(formData.dob) : "" }
    ];

    fields.forEach(field => {
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      label.textContent = field.label;
      fieldset.appendChild(label);

      var input;
      if (field.type === "select") {
        input = document.createElement("select");
        field.options.forEach(optionValue => {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = optionValue;
          option.text = optionValue;
          if (optionValue === field.selected) option.selected = true;
          input.appendChild(option);
        });
      } else {
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = field.type;
        input.value = field.value;
      }

      input.name = field.name;
      input.classList.add("form-control", "mb-3");
      fieldset.appendChild(input);
    });

    parent.appendChild(fieldset);
  }
}

// Example call to addAdultFields (ensure this is called after the DOM is loaded)
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Call this function as needed, e.g., on some event or user action
  document.getElementById("numberofAdults").addEventListener('change', addAdultFields);
});



the second step of the multi step form is where the field should appear
<div id="adultFormcontainer" ></div>

when I run my code it does create the field and has the firstname ,lastname and Gender but calculating the age is the problem. when I remove the calculate age function I see the dob on the console
here is what my console looks like


Why don't you take input from user and process in backend? What server language or backend technology you are using? Do you need something like this

All you needed to do was add a div with the ID "adultFormContainer" after the rest of the form.
The way it is now works fine, unless your customer enters the date of birth as MMDDYYYY, and then it doesn't.
A different way you could do it is by replacing the text entry with a date entry, like so:
<input type="date" name="dob" class=" form-control" placeholder="DateOfBirth" id="mdate-3">

And by doing that, it will format the date string always the same, so your function doesn't have to be changed. You might also want to put a max date on the date picker, to make sure people don't pick a date after today, or before 18 years ago, etc., but that is your decision, based on what this is being used for.
